# Sidebar jumps uncontrollably when the height is modified on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar on my site that is fixed to the side and when the user scrolls down or up, the style attribute top is changed so that the height is adjusted.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 125){
        var v = 125 - $(this).scrollTop();
        $("#sidebar").css({'top':v + 'px'});
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 125)
    {
        $("#sidebar").css({'top':'5px'});
    }
});
```

However, when I scroll down, the sidebar seems to jump uncontrollably and does not stick to the screen as I would like. I am using Chrome 32 so I don't see what the problem is. Please can someone help me with this issue.

Comment: You need to provide more code and/or a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/B55W7/

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/k4Amv/) fiddle.

Create a CSS class called fixed.

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```

On scroll, in your JavaScript add and remove the "fixed" class accordingly to make the proper effect.

**JavaScript**:

```
$(function () {
    var $sidebar = $('#sidebar');
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        if($(this).scrollTop() < 125) {
            $sidebar.removeClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $sidebar.addClass('fixed');  
        }
    });
});
```

As the header scrolls out of the window, the sidebar gets the "fixed" class and sticks to the side of the screen at the top left (0,0) respectively. When the header is coming back into view, the class is removed and the sidebar moves gracefully back to it's original position.